# How to change image cache time for all images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How is it possible to change image cache expire time for all images? I can see with Google Page speed it is 12 hours. I want to change this to one week.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using and what web server are you using? Are the images on s3?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would want [Customizing the asset path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html)